What files does IronPython require in the C:\Python27 folder?
We use IronPython 2.7 in a desktop app, which is used to programmatically run simple Python scripts which  might import standard modules like 'sys', 'time', and so on. It retrieves these from the C:\Python\Lib\ folder, which is passed to ScriptEngine.SetSearchPaths().
Up until now we've been deploying the full C:\Python27 folder to customer PCs, which is a lot to send, so I was wondering if this can be trimmed down, for example only deploying .py files in C:\Python27\Lib? Or will these files have their own dependencies on other files and subfolders within here?

The whole IronPython download is less than 10mb zipped and the Lib folder is 11mb unzipped, which doesn't seem big enough to care about unless you have some extreme requirements (regardless of if we're talking about data transfer or unzipped space on disk). Regarding your question - yes there are lots of interdependencies between the standard library modules, e.g. csv imports re. If you know what parts of the standard lib you use directly, it should be possible to wade through the lib code and remove some unused parts, but again I highly doubt it's worth the effort.

@l4mpi I'm not sure which version you are looking at but my \Lib subfolder zips up to 40Mb. We often have to install at customer sites over TeamViewer where file transfers are extremely slow. I was hoping a simple solution would be to only distribute the \Lib files (but none of the subfolders in here, where the bulk of the content is). Like you say though, it's probably not worth the effort of figuring out what is needed, or the risk of missing something important.

I was looking at the latest IronPython 2.7 release .zip on github (https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/releases/download/ipy-2.7.12/IronPython.2.7.12.zip). Maybe your Lib folder includes some additional things, e.g. some pip-installed modules in site-packages? In the official release the only subfolders of Lib are python stdlib packages with multiple submodules, such as xml or multiprocessing. If your distribution Lib folder includes .pyc/.pyo files, you should be able to safely delete them as these are just the compiled versions of the.py files and will be recreated on demand.
